# MGTwitterEngine: Which user is logged in?

Tags: oauth, mgtwitterengine, xauth

I'd like to know how can I know which user is logged in at the moment? I'm using xAuth, and I'm not using the SAOAuthTwitterEngine, so I'm limited to the MGTwitterEngine methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering myself: the method checkUserCredentials in MGTwitterEngine brings the info of the current authenticated user.